# Matching Differences between two documents

Tags: algorithm, matching, string-matching, locality-sensitive-hash, textmatching

i have a set of strings along with their co-ordinates and rectangular bounds int two similar pages. these strings are different in three possible ways. 
(i) a string can be moved to a new location on a page.
(ii) a string is in the same location but it is modified. say ( abc --> abd or ABC)
(iii) a combination of (i) and (ii).
(iv) a string might be missing.

i tried to use locality sensitive hashing but couldn't find a good hash function for this. Can anyone please suggest me a good hash function or another algorithm to solve this problem. thanks in advance

Comment: What's your cost function? For example, how many characters can be different in a match before you'd prefer the algorithm to instead report that the string's missing?

Comment: for now it's min(wordsize/2,4).

Comment: Couple of other things: is every string in the "target" page present in the "source" page? Do the strings change length, or are there only letter substitutions? Are the strings disjoint?

Comment: Oh, and do you know the boundaries between the strings in the target page as well as in the source page?

Comment: not necessarily....that's listed as case (iv) and no the strings need not be disjoint.a similar string cam be present in many locations.yes i know the location of the string in the page including the rectangular bounds of the string.

Comment: Okay. Is this an accurate phrasing of your problem then: "Given a set of strings S and another set T such that |S| >= |T|, find an injective map from S to T that minimizes the sum of a cost function?"

Comment: nope not exactly.a few strings in s might not have a match in T and a few strings in T might not have a match in s.

Answer (score 2):

So we have a list of source strings `S` and a list of target strings `T` of size at most `|S|`. We want find a way to assign each string in `T` to a distinct string in `S` such that the total number of mismatched characters is minimized

(Note that because we're looking for a way to match `T` to `S`, the case where a string in `S` is missing is dealt with implicitly)

If this is an accurate interpretation of your problem @programer8, I believe this is an [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem) and can be solved by the [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) in cubic time: the "workers" referred to in the wiki article are your target strings, the "tasks" are the source strings, and the number of mismatched characters between a source and a target string is the cost of a worker performing a task.

The only hiccup is you have fewer workers/target strings than tasks/source strings, but you can remedy that by adding dummy workers.

Comment: i checked this algorithm a few days ago.this is not feasible because of the run time but this will get the job done.

Comment: What runtime does it need to be feasible?

Comment: And are you willing to accept approximations to the solution? If so, how good do they need to be?

Comment: if i do accept approximations...can you suggest me a better algorithm ? do you have an algorithm already on your mind?

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of a greedy algorithm like [this one](http://download.peerialism.com/papers/ExtendedAbstract.pdf), but I've realised that even if you can find a sub-cubic time solution for the assignment problem, it doesn't help much because getting the O(n^2) costs can take up to cubic time anyway. To go any faster I think you're right that we need to exploit something about the string-y nature of the problem, rather than abstracting away to a general assignment problem. Will keep thinking about it.